# C++ MFC Message handling

Tags: c++, mfc

So I'm making an MFC application that handles a couple of different messages and will display different output based on which message was handled. So right now I have one that handles the `WM_KEYDOWN` message and displays that message's output. Now I also have one that handles `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` and what I want it to do is to start up the game of Brick Breaker that I am making. The issue that I'm having is that once I enter the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` I want to disable certain keys so that I can control the paddle without calling the `WM_KEYDOWN`.

TL:DR How do you disable certain keys from the `WM_KEYDOWN`in MFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override [`PreTranslateMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkbhxcs2.aspx) to see and bypass a message before MFC does its message map translation.

Comment: So what really had to be done was to override the `PreTranslateMessage` and then add some accelerators to the class for  the virtual keys for the left and right arrows keys.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to *disable* keys in your application. When another program has the focus, all input should go to that program.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to forward the keys you are interested in to the code that drives your object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disable keys. It is simply up to your code to decide to process or not a key according to the state of the application.